# Getting TimeZone instance from a date

Tags: java

With the following code-

```
    Timestamp ts = (Timestamp)results.get(0);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(ts.getTime())));
```

I get output as: 04/29/2013 15:08:30 +0530

I wanted to create a TimeZone instance from the timestamp, so tried this-

```
    SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
    String tzString = FORMATTER.format(ts);

    // the tzString comes out to be +0530 (which is correct)

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(tzString);
    System.out.println(tz);
```

But the final TimeZone instance is of GMT as its not able to identify +0530.

So, how can I get a correct TimeZone instance here?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get a TimeZone from a java.sql.Timestamp because it does not contain one. In your case you are simply getting your default TimeZone. It does not make sense. It is the same as TimeZone.getDefault();

Comment: I guess you are right. Though I am getting TimeZone instance from a date, its not the one of the database.

Comment: Anyway, date is just milliseconds, no timezone. It would make sense if you were getting it from a string representation of a date with timezone.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to use HQL to get the database timezone. Let me see if Hibernate allows to get the timezone string out of the database. Want to make it generic so that it works for all databases.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lowercase `z` in your pattern. That should return `"GMT+0530"`, which will work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `SimpleDateFormat`, you can simply do this:-

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(ts.getTime()));
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
System.out.println(tz);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code below:

```
  Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Then to get the TimeZone instance from the timestamp, I did this:

```
  SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
  TimeZone tzone = FORMATTER.getTimeZone();
  System.out.println(tzone.getDisplayName());
  System.out.println(tzone.getID());
```

I got:

```
Central European Time
Europe/Berlin
```

So I got my timezone which is +0200 instead of GMT.

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: That's local time zone I suppose, as ts (Timestamp) is not used at all.